# How to serve different pages with different servers

Tags: domain, apache-2.4, http

I like to do some testing now and then and I like trying out new things in different languages, but I only have 1 server.
I would like to serve my main website from 1 server (preferably apache, since it's currently wordpress and some other php stuff) and other pages from a different server (WEBRick, django, maybe something else).
It would all be running on the same host, and I would prefer if all of it ran on port 80. Beyond that I can do whatever is best. Subdomains work (and currently I use phusion passenger for rails stuff on subdomains), different server side folders would work (example.com/stuff).

Assuming it's easiest to do all this with domains/subdomains, which wouldn't be a problem. I just need to know how to send requests to a specific subdomain to a different server. I can also change iptables configuration (not sure if that helps).

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Is it that trivial or unimportant to have multiple webservers on the same machine wanting them to have port 80 ? I'm confused.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe it's because your question doesn't show any research efforts...

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I will agree. Had I known to search for reverse proxy I would have found all kinds of stuff. Without that, however, it's hard to find anything.

I do apologize for asking the question. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I think you don't have to apologize - it's more that many people who are active on this site are in favor of "helping people help themselves" and "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime".. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use two different web servers, you need to deal with Apache Reverse Proxies. Set your main server (Apache for instance) to port 80 and have it managing all your main site. Set up another web server (nginx) on another port like 81 for other sites.

In your Apache configuration, you need to set up a VirtualHost that ReverseProxy's to the other web server. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

What this configuration does is tell Apache to look to the web server at localhost:81, and proxy the served pages over. The ProxyPreserveHost is important because it passes the host name to the other web server, so you can have multiple VirtualHosts there too.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by putting a **reverse proxy** before your servers and direct to the proper one when request for particular site is sent to that proxy.

You can use mod_proxy of Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Or you can try something more lightweight like ngnix.